# Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0 Provider is not registered in the local machine

Tags: c#-3.0

Dot net windows application using access database in *Windows 7 32 bit*. On installing this application in other 64 bit system gives error  '`Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0 Provider is not registered in the local machine`'.

So I installed `AccessDatabaseEngine_x64` and ran my applications which seem to work correctly  but *uninstalling the same application and installing again* gives same error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.12.0 with Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

and I am sure, you must have installed

2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue open the project in Visual Studio then:

1. From the solution explorer right-click your project then click Properties
2. Click the Build tab
3. Change Platform target from: Any CPU to x86
4. Re-build your solution